# Angular 5 i18n Directive Using Rest Call

Tags: angular

How can we create a custom directive for i18n feature, which takes the json from rest call and store in a service ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Angular has built-in support for i18n, and if you want something more dynamic, there is ngx-translate. If you don't even know where to start, you should definitely use one of those (and even if you know, BTW)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of the json file? And why would it need to be "stored" in a service? Please be more specify. And I can only support @JBNizet: Have a look at the built-in support and at ngx-tranlsate.